# My PS4 controller not connecting

Tags: ps4, controllers

Okay so I went to my friends house the other day and he wanted me to bring my PS4 controller as he only had 1. So when I got to his I connected my controller to his PS4 with no problem. But when I got back to my house I wanted to play ps; so I did the usual thing which is to use the leed but my controller didn't connect. 
These are the things that I have tried:

- The share and PS button
- reset button
- the leed
- turning off PS4
- unplugged the PS4

Answer (score 0):

It is fundamentally important that you press the PS button on the controller in question while the PS4 is powering up, and the blue light is blinking - do not wait until the system prompts you to press the PS button, it's too late.

1. Turn off console.
2. Connect controller with micro-USB cable.
3. Turn on console manually (button on front left of PS4), and when the button lights up blue press the PS button on the controller.

In my recent experience the system took a couple of extra seconds to recognize the controller, but then it worked. I too tried all of the above troubleshooting techniques and none of them worked until I got the all-important timing correct. You'd think Sony would take care to mention this little detail.

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your answer! Although in future, try not to post the [exact](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/327925/ps4-controller-not-connecting/334826#334826) [same](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/334827/28182) answer to multiple questions, this tends to kick off a lot of automated warnings and stuff. If a question is the exact same, you can [flag them as a duplicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), otherwise, try and tailor your answers specifically to the question as asked. Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

Please be sure to follow these steps

- Start your PS4 (any way you like)
- Connect the NEW controller with an USB cable to the front USB port
- Press the PS button on the controller

should work any time. If not, try another USB cable (might be an issue there) and let your controller charrge for a while

good luck!

Comment: I've personally experienced issues where this definitely does not work.  It's not as cut and dry as you think.